# Can we connect the android phone with pc as com port and send command from phone to com port

Tags: android, windows, android-ndk

I am on an RnD of a project in which I need to connect my phone to the usb port and create a com port so that I can send some command to an embeded system connect to the same pc and open and waiting to receive command on the communication port.

I need to control that device using my mobile and it should be through com port. Any solution or suggestion please help me I don't know whether we can send command to a device connect to computer on a com port by connecting my device on an other com port on that machine.

Comment: Are you able to connect android device to com port ?